# R Calling internal function from an exported function inside package

Tags: r, r-package

I am creating an R package in RStudio. Say I have two functions `fnbig()` and `fnsmall()` in my package named `foo`. `fnbig()` is a function that must be accessible to the user using the package. `fnsmall()` is an internal function that must not accessible to the user but should be accessible inside of `fnbig()`.

```
# package code
fnsmall <- function()
{
bla bla..
}

#' @export
fnbig <- function()
{
bla bla..
x <- fnsmall()
bla..
}
```

I have tried exporting `fnsmall()`. All works but it litters the NAMESPACE. I tried not exporting `fnsmall()`, but then it doesn't work inside `fnbig()` when using `x <- fnsmall()` or `x <- foo::fnsmall()`. Then I tried to use `x <- foo:::fnsmall()`, and it works. But I read that using `:::`is not recommended.

What is the best way to go about doing this? How do I call an internal function from an exported function?

Comment: The code you have posted should work as is. Could you share some more detail on how to replicate the problems you're seeing?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Do your error messages indicate that `fnbig` is not exported, or do they complain about `fnsmall` not being exported?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> But I read that using :::is not recommended.

I think you mention this based on the following statement in the [manual for writing packages by R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html).

> Using `foo:::f` instead of `foo::f` allows access to unexported objects. This is generally not recommended, as the semantics of unexported objects may be changed by the package author in routine maintenance.

The reason for this to be not recommended is that unexported functions have no documentation and as such have no guarantee from the side of the package author that they will keep doing what they do now.

However, since you are referring to your own unexported functions, you have full control of what is happening in those functions, so this objection is not as relevant.

Referring to it as `foo:::fnsmall` is therefore a good option.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on this. I have exactly the same problem, however R CMD now gives a warning for referencing your own internal functions with `:::` is there any way around this?

Comment: If the internal function (`foo:::fnsmall`) is referenced in your own package (`foo`), then you don't need to reference it internally. Instead, you can call the function as if it's any other function in your package: `fnsmall`